# How can I initialize a type that is a pointer to a struct in Go?

Tags: pointers, struct, types, go, initialization

For example:

```
type Foo struct {
        x int
}
var foo *Foo = &Foo{5}

type Bar *struct {
        x int
}
var bar Bar = ??
```

How can I initialize `bar`?

I realize there is a workaround:

```
type Bar *Foo
var bar Bar = &Foo{5}
```

But I would like to avoid that.

Comment: According to the Go team, you should not make types pointers to structs. Always make types structs and add pointers where necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [probably] no reason to ever use the form `type Bar *struct`. The type is a pointer to an anonymous struct, so you have to initialize it with an anonymous struct (or as you point out, an equivalent, convertible struct type).

```
var b Bar = &struct{x int}{}
// or
b := Bar(&Foo{})
```

The declaration is essentially the same is

```
type Bar *Foo
```

Which may make it a little more clear what you're trying to do.

But again, this is non-idiomatic, and you will probably encounter resistance using this in a team setting or public interface (i.e. I personally wouldn't pass this is code review)

Comment: Whenever you say "there's no reason to ever do X", you're probably wrong. I my case, I have a set of types that all implement the same interface. However, some of them are supposed to work with pointer receivers and others with value receivers. In order to not have to change all my code every time I change whether a type is a pointer type or a value type, it would be better to just declare the pointer types as pointers. (I hope that doesn't sound to confusing.)

Comment: @Matt: good point, there are almost always exceptions ;) Though I don't think that's a valid reason to go down this path. You're trying to hide the pointer in a very non-idiomatic way, and I would venture to say it's going to be awkward and less maintainable. Switching from pointer to value receivers is usually a very quick refactor. The compiler tells you exactly what lines to change.

Comment: It's not switching the receivers that's difficult. It's changing every `*Foo` to `Foo` and `(&foo).X` to `foo.X` in the rest of my code that's difficult.

Comment: @matt, that's what I'm talking about. The compiler will tell you where they are (maybe some editor/IDE plugins do too?). Plus, due to addressability and automatic referencing/dereferencing, many don't need to be changed http://play.golang.org/p/uImXTAh6Ll

Comment: Still that means that I have to change a package's interface just because I changed the implementation.

Comment: I realize now that Go doesn't even allow me to add methods to `Bar`, so there goes that idea...